# Send a model to MVC3 controller by setting src of element

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm attempting to trigger a download of an Excel document. My controller returns the downloadable file:

```
public ActionResult ExportPatchSchedules([Bind(Prefix = "multiSelectDialog")] ExportPatchSchedulesModel model)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = WorkflowManager.ExportPatchScheduleReport(model.TaskIDs);

    return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        string.Format(@"Patch Schedule Report {0}.xls", string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}", DateTime.Now)));
}
```

In order to trigger the download,  I've got the following:

```
$('<iframe>', {
    src: '../Workflow/ExportPatchSchedules/',
    css: {
        display: 'none'
    }
}).appendTo('body');
```

However, previously, I was using an AJAX request to get to my controller's method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../Workflow/ExportPatchSchedules',
    data: formData
});
```

where formData is the serialized representation of ExportPatchSchedulesModel.

I'm struggling with sending my model to ExportPatchSchedules when I'm restricted to setting the src. Is it possible to send my model across in this way? If not.. how is this usually done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use an html `form` with it's `target` attribute set to the `name` of your `iframe`, something like:

```
<iframe style="display: none;" id="myIframe" name="myIframe"></iframe>

var f = document.createElement("form");
f.method = "POST";
f.action = "../Workflow/ExportPatchSchedules";
f.target = "myIframe";
f.enctype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; // not sure about this since you didn't mention

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = "hidden";
input.name = "model";
input.value = "...." // your data here, not sure about it since you didn't mention

f.appendChild(input);
f.submit();
```